# Memory leak with presentViewController in iOS Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

I am writing a Keyboard Extension for iOS in Objective-C. At one point in `viewController1`, I present another View Controller by

```
CustomViewController *viewController2 = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:viewController2 animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The problem occurs in the following scenario: another app is open with my extension as active keyboard. `viewController2` is being presented and the extension is exited (by pressing the home button). When the app is restarted, `viewController2` is not shown anymore, but `viewController1` is. From the memory consumption I can see that `viewController2` is still in memory. Repeating the steps in this paragraph quickly leads to a crash because of too much memory consumption.

This does not happen when normal user actions are performed in `viewController2`, after which

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

is called. Further, I made 100% sure there are no strong references that could lead to a memory leak. I also tried to receive a message when (`viewWillDisappear` etc) to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO`, but it seems pushing the home button instantly kills the extension.

`viewController1` is a `UIInputViewController`and acts as a delegate for a `CLLocationManager` and a `UICollectionView`, `viewController2` is a `UIViewController` and does not act as a delegate at all. I do not keep any reference from `viewController1` to `viewController2`, and a weak one from `viewController2` to `viewController1`.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) viewController1 *parent;
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? What can I do to prevent this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please show some surrounding code. This may be a delegate cross strong reference issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have updated my question, I hope it helps. I am quite new to OOP, so please tell me if my answer is not sufficient!

Comment: Your formatting is great, hopefully someone will be able to help you. I can't figure this out either :-)